# Execute SQL stored using ado.net

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I am using ado.net to access sql server I have costum Stored Procedure I am executing it using ado.net :

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Custom",con);
```

and i am sending the parameters like this :

```
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Parm1",SqlDbType.Int,0,"Parm1"));

            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Parm2",SqlDbType.Int,0,"Parm2"))
```

it dose not work and it did not give me an error as well it is the first time to work  without DAL generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to make it work add this line before set the params :

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

and set the params using :

```
 command.Parameters[0].Value=4;

 command.Parameters[1].Value=2;
```

:)

Comment: My fault :( I have debug the code a lot but i did not search enough I thought that there is something wrong but not something missing :(

Comment: @ your service but search enough before asking and it happens with me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Please, use this pattern:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("nameOfMyStoredProcedure", mySqlConnectionObject);  
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);  
command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = customerID;
```

Comment: Last 2 lines can be combined to

    command.Paramters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = customerID;

Comment: Personally I like to create the SqlParameters as separate objects and then add them after the command string (at the top of the method) it becomes much easier to read the code if you see the command string and parameters before you dive into the code that just sets up sql statements